# @FeignClient is not failing in Type Mismatch

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud-netflix, netflix-feign

I am intentionally trying to simulate a failure condition. I have a service which returns JSON of a `User` object. However, in `@FeignClient` `@RequestMapping` I am returning another object i.e. `Event`.

In this case, I was expecting Feign to fail deserializing the JSON to the `Event` POJO. But it is not failing. Moreover, the response `Event` object is also not null.

So my question is, is this the behavior by design? What I can do to make Feign fail in this kind of situation.

Here is my FeignClient.

```
@FeignClient(name = "userProxy", url = "${securei.url}")
public interface UserProxy {

    @RequestMapping(value = IUser.USER_LOGIN, method = RequestMethod.GET, params = {"u", "p"})
    public Event login(@RequestParam("u") String username, @RequestParam("p") String password);

}
```

Here the actual login service returns the User JSON, however I have provided Event as the return type. Still, it is not failing.

Comment: Please provide the relevant part of your code. Add a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) including proper example input/output data.

Comment: Please see my recent edit.

Comment: Did you specify @EnableFeignClients somewhere?

Comment: @Bsquare yes, I have the application class annotated with that.

Comment: @Bsquare actually FeignClient works fine as it should be, It's just not failing.

Comment: Did you try setting a [fallback](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-netflix/multi/multi_spring-cloud-feign.html#spring-cloud-feign-hystrix-fallback)? I guess you may intercept this kind of error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184020/discussion-between-soumitri-pattnaik-and-bsquare).